# Mostrar datos del usuario logeado

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo varios usuarios con datos y roles distintos, pueden logearse con su correo y contraseña, pero al momento de mostrar datos en su perfil se muestran todos los datos de mi tabla user y no del usuario en especifico.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl2I2.png
```

¿Hay alguna manera que pueda mostrarse solo los datos del usuario logeado? Gracias de antemano

Dejo mi codigo:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  error_reporting(0);

  $validar = $_SESSION['correo'];

  if( $validar == null || $validar = ''){

   header("Location: inicio.php");
   die();
  }?>

 <?php include("header.html"); ?>
 <?php include("navbar.php"); ?>

  <div class="main">
  <h2 style="color: white;">Perfil:</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <section>
        <img src="../img/icons/avatar.png" style="width: 25%";>
      </section>
        <div class="card-body">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <?php

              ?>
              <tr>
                <td>Nombre: </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Apellido:  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td>Cedula: </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Telefono:  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Correo: <?php echo $_SESSION['correo']; ?> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Cargo: </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include("footer.html");?>
```

Comment: Muestra donde asignas el valor a `$_SESSION['correo']`

Comment: Al principio: $validar = $_SESSION['correo']; esto lo identifica entre los otros usuarios

Comment: Como asignas previamente la variable $_SESSION['correo'] ? desde un controlador, desde otra vista? es importante saber como esta siendo asignada previo a esta vista

Comment: Si, utilizo una function para iniciar sesion del usuario pero eso queda en otro archivo